# Bash: Negating the output of the 'cmp' command doesn't work

Tags: bash, if-statement, exit-code

I have a bash script that checks if a file already exists or has changed. If either of these case are true, copy the file from one location to anther.

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE}" )/my-dir" && pwd )"
FILE="file.json"

copy() {
  local SAME=$(cmp --silent "${DIR}/${FILE}" "${PWD}/${FILE}")

  if [ ! -f "${PWD}/${FILE}" ] || [ ! $SAME ]; then
    cp "${DIR}/${FILE}" "${PWD}/${FILE}" && echo "'$FILE' has been copied." || echo "Copy of '$FILE' has failed.";
  else
    echo "'$FILE' already exists and has not changed (not copied).";
  fi;
}

copy
```

But when the file exists and has **not** changed, it is still copied.

`echo "$SAME"` doesn't echo anything but `echo $?` echos the exit code **0**

So my question is: is it possible to negate the output of the 'cmp' command in a condition?

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't quoting `$SAME`, so if it is indeed empty, your test is actually `[ ! ]`, which is *always* true since `!` is a non-empty string.

Comment: `SAME` is not the exit code but output of `cmp` command.

Comment: @TylerDurden Here is what the http://stackoverflow.com/tour page says: `Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.`

Comment: keep reading: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers". You have failed to produce the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is clear (the condition doesn't pass) and I'm actually asking for a general programming question about Bash starting from a code error. It includes the desired behaviour and the actual error. And if you are not lazy, two `echo "whatever" > file.json` make the code reproductible. I don't understand you point.

Comment: On the other hand, http://shellcheck.com does recommend quoting `$SAME` (although it doesn't quite get the reason right). So the request in the tag wiki "For shell scripts with errors, please check them in http://shellcheck.net before posting here." would probably have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your parameter expansion. If `$SAME` is the empty string (and it always will be, because you use `--silent`), your test devolves to `[ ! ]`. Because `!` is a non-empty string, the test succeeds.

```
if [ ! -f "${PWD}/${FILE}" ] || [ ! "$SAME" ]; then
```

`SAME` also needs to *contain* the output of `cmp`:

```
SAME=$(cmp "${DIR}/${FILE}" "${PWD}/${FILE}")
```

However, it would be better to ignore the actual output of `cmp` and use its exit status instead.

```
if [ ! -f "$PWD/$FILE" ] || ! cmp --silent "${DIR}/${FILE}" "${PWD}/${FILE}"; then
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Subsequent question to provide people who may run on this post with full answers, what is the difference between quoted and unquoted variables in this situation?

Comment: As in any situation, an unquoted parameter expansion is subject to word-splitting, resulting in one word per non-empty string separated by characters in `IFS`. If the expansion is empty, zero words are produces. A quoted expansion, on the other hand, is a definite, though possibly empty, string that produces exactly one word.